# Spark SQL UDF from a string which represents scala code at runtime

Tags: scala, apache-spark, apache-spark-sql, user-defined-functions, scala-reflect

I need to be able to register a udf from a string which I will get from a web service, i.e at run time I call a web service to get the scala code which constitutes the udf, compile it and register it as an udf in the spark context. As as example let's say my web service return the following scala code in a json response -

```
(row: Row, field:String) => {
import scala.util.{Try, Success, Failure}
val index: Int = Try(row.fieldIndex(field)) match {
    case Success(_) => 1
    case Failure(_) => 0
}
index
})
```

I want to compile this code on the fly and then register it as an udf. I have already multiple options such as using toolbox, twitter eval util etc. but found that I need to explicity specify the arguments types of the method while creating an instance for ex -

```
val code =
  q"""
   (a:String, b:String) => {
      a+b
   }
 """
val compiledCode = toolBox.compile(code)
val compiledFunc = compiledCode().asInstanceOf[(String, String) => Option[Any]]
```

This udf takes two strings as arguments hence I need to specify the types while creating the object like

```
compiledCode().asInstanceOf[(String, String) => Option[Any]]
```

The other option I explored is 
https://stackoverflow.com/a/34371343/1218856

In both the cases I have to know the no of arguments, argument types and the return type before hand to instantiate the code as a method. But in my case as the udfs are created my users, I have no control over the no of arguments and thier types, so I would like to know if there any way I can register the UDF by compiling the scala code with out knowing the argument number and type information.

In a nut shell, I get the code as string, compile it and register it as udf without knowing the type information.

Answer (score 1):

I think you'd be much better off by not trying to generate/execute code directly but defining a different kind of expression language and executing that. Something like ANTLR could help you with writing the grammar of that expression language and generating the parser and the Abstract Syntax Trees. Or even scala's parser combinators. It's of course more work but also a far less risky and error-prone way of allowing custom function execution.